# Centering table cell inside wrapper table - 3 column, fluid layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, centering, css-tables, fluid-layout

My third attempt recoding my site for a responsive layout based on more suggestions from Stack Overflow members. This time I'm using a **display:table** / **display:table-cell** setup to center a page wrapper whose height is controlled by content and a sticky footer.

A member suggested a basic layout that works (thanks!) BUT I cannot center my inline wrapper inside my page wrapper if I use a width less than 100%. It forces the inline-wrapper to the right of the page-wrapper.

I've tried margins, padding and text-align. I could probably hack it with the "center" tag but I want my code to be semantic.

This is a condensed view of my code - I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, missing syntax (I forgot a comma earlier that cost me 30mins troubleshooting), it needs a hack for ie10 and Opera or whatever.

```
<div id="page-wrapper>
 <div id="logo"><img /></div>
 <div id="inline-wrapper">
  <div id="top-content">
   <div id="left"><img /></div>
   <div id="center">content blah blah</div>
   <div id="right"><img /></div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav-menu"><ul><li><img /></li></ul></div>
  <div id="main-content">
   <div id="left"><img /></div>
   <div id="center">content blah blah</div>
   <div id="right"><img /></div>
  </div>
</div></div>
<div id="footer"></div>

html, body, #page-wrapper, #inline-wrapper, #top-content, #main-content {
      height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
}

#page-wrapper {
    height:100%;/* to show footer */
    width:70%;
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    border:solid;
}
#logo {
    width:100%;
    top:.75%;
    z-index:99;
    position:absolute;
}
#logo > img {
    width:100%;
}
#inline-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell; <-- /* I removed this */
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding-bottom:1%;
}

#top-content, #main-content {
     display:table;
     width:98%;
     border-collapse:collapse;
}
#top-content {
     height:60%;
}

#right, #left, #center {
    display:table-cell;
}

#left {
    background-color:#CC0000;
    width:14%;
}

#left img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#right {
    background:#0600ff;
    width:14%;
}

#center {   
    width:72%;
    background:#ccc;
}

#nav-menu {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;  
}

#nav-menu li {
    color:#fff;
    margin:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#000000;
    list-style-position:inside;
    border:1% solid #ffffff;
    padding:.75%;
    width:12.5%;
    height:31%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#nav-menu li:hover {
    opacity: .55;
  filter: alpha(opacity=55);
}

#nav-menu li img {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#footer {
  width:100%;
  height:250px;
  background-color:#000;
  border-top:solid;
}
```

Comment: ugh - just read a forum thread of someone having a similar problem and their solution was to use ANOTHER wrapper and give it display:inline-block. am I going to be forced to add another wrapper???

Comment: figured it out ... their layout put display:table-cell on the inline-wrapper. I removed it, and it centered perfectly! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try clossing the id there: `<div id="page-wrapper>`. Change it to this: <`div id="page-wrapper">`